# What is the correct way to configure CSP in Tauri when using CSS-in-JS libraries?

Tags: rust, styled-components, tauri, css-in-js

In the release build, Tauri does not render anything. After a bit of Googling, I found the same [issue](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/discussions/5723), but I am still confused about the right CSP configuration to set when using CSS-in-JS libraries like styled-components.

Right now, this is my CSP:
`"csp": "default-src 'self'"`

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally ended up with this configuration in the tauri.conf.json file. Is this the right way to do it? I don't know. I'm leaving my answer here so people who come here may find this useful.

```json
  "security": {
      "dangerousDisableAssetCspModification": ["style-src"],
      "csp": "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' asset:"
    }
```

EDIT:

> Based on my own experience, I've never seen an attack that leveraged the injection of CSS to cause harm. - https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/

I guess "unsafe-inline" is okay.

Related: https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/discussions/8578

Answer (score 0):

So for production build here's a CSP configuration you want:

```json
"security": {
      "csp": "default-src 'self' style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
},
```

According to [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-4-css-encode-and-strictly-validate-before-inserting-untrusted-data-into-html-style-property-values) and [CSP](https://content-security-policy.com) reference adding `unsafe-inline` is not secure for the Web, but it context of Tauri it's a smaller risk you have to evaluate.

Overall it's a problem of how [Vite](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/11862) packages CSP, including styled-components.

If you want to keep debugging this, this vite and babel [configuration](https://github.com/developermindsetcom/tauri-styled-components/blob/master/vite.config.ts#L8-L13) might be relevant.

======

Here's the [source code](https://github.com/developermindsetcom/tauri-styled-components/blob/master/src/App.tsx).

Used default example:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: palevioletred;
`;

//.....

return (
    <div className="container">
      <Title>Welcome to Tauri!</Title>
//...
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried building it, I am getting the error in the production build not in the dev build.

Comment: Okay, updated the answer with `"csp": "default-src 'self' style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"` also check out the code changes on github. Solution is not ideal but if you deploy it with certain configurations (only local CSS/HTML and no XSS, eval, injections, etx.) then you might be okay. DYOR

Comment: One more idea is to generate hash during Vite build and specify it inside Tauri's CSP: `"csp": "default-src 'self'; style-src 'sha256-XYZ"`